# How to debug Apple Push Notification Response?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I wrote a python app that sends push notification to Apple devices.

Suddenly notifications are no longer received, on all the iOS apps.

It looks like Apple returns an error after sending the notification.

I would like to know if the following response looks normal?, or if there is an issue with the certificates?

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert /home/ubuntu/webapps/notification/certificates/relax_app/production/apns-dev-cert.pem -key /home/ubuntu/webapps/notification/certificates/relax_app/production/apns-dev-key-noenc.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = "Entrust, Inc.", OU = www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference, OU = "(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc.", CN = Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
140149704410784:error:14094415:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate expired:s3_pkt.c:1195:SSL alert number 45
140149704410784:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:591:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2670 bytes and written 2047 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: F2FEDB49795DA0B3084B850521A514EB60EE9959C40753AB79B799CA4F6225DAA4FE7084B8CF6D7BF9A4AEB92B9B3A06
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1385498375
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

**Note**

The response returns the following:
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate

Does this error prevent sending push notifications? or can it be ignored?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you didn't connect to apn server success,the error means something went wrong while connecting to HTTPS sites with “openssl s_client”:  http://lost-and-found-narihiro.blogspot.jp/2013/03/openssl-sclient-verify-errornum20unable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The issue was related with expired and revoked certificates.

New certificates were generated according to this great tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/